# How do I select values from one table by excluding the values present in the second table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Below are just sample tables. The question is how to select `dt` and `memberID` from the user table only for dates on which the users were active and did not make any payments?

I tried using Except but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Payments table (users who made payments on these dates)

[image]

User Table (Users who were active on these dates)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such case you can use left join, not exists, not in but I am giving solution using left join

```
Select u.DT, u.member_Id
From user u
Left join payment p on p.member_id = u.member_id
    And u.DT = p.dt
Where p.member_Id is null
And u.DT between <start_date>  and  <end_date> --if you want to compare date range otherwise use equal instead of between for single date comparison.
```

Comment: This gives a null set. There are dates for which both the dt and the memberID is same. so i'm not sure if one join is going to work here. Could you have a look at it again please? @susang

Comment: Updated please check.

Answer (score 1):

I think this SQL suits your requirement:

```
Select u.memberID, u.Dt from Users u left join Payments p 
 on u.memberID = p.memberID
  and u.Dt = p.Dt
where p.amount is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a `not exists` or similar query:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1 from payments p where p.memberid = m.memberid);
```

Comment: this returns an empty set for some reason.

Comment: select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1 from payments p where p.memberid = u.memberid and p.dt = u.dt)

do you think this is correct though?

Comment: @emkay . . . This seems to be the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: Thanks! @ gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

we can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`  for that like this:

```
SELECT u.dt, u.memberID
FROM User u
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payments p ON p.dt = u.dt AND u.memberID = p.memberID
WHERE 
  p.amount IS NULL
ORDER BY u.dt, u.memberID
```

The results :

```
|         dt | memberID |
|------------|----------|
| 2018-01-01 |        5 |
| 2018-01-02 |        3 |
| 2018-01-02 |        4 |
| 2018-01-03 |        4 |
| 2018-01-03 |        5 |
| 2018-01-04 |        2 |
| 2018-01-06 |        1 |
| 2018-01-06 |        2 |
| 2018-01-06 |        6 |
| 2018-01-07 |        3 |
| 2018-01-07 |        4 |
```